# How to output multiple line mysql string from database without quotes

Tags: php, html

I'm retrieving a string from a database that was entered by a form, but if the string is to long, it's generated with double quotes in the html.
This is how I'm retrieving the data:

```
echo '<p>' . $descr['field_value'] . '</P>';
```

When I view the html source, the browser adds double quotes.

short single line strings do not show up with quotes.

Is there a way to force php to display strings without quotes?

Comment: PHP wouldn't be adding quotes to your data, and the database shouldn't either. If quotes are appearing, it would have to be when the data's being inserted into the DB in the first place. Have you run the queries manually from the mysql monitor to see what comes out, without PHP being involved?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `echo '<p>' . htmlspecialchars($desc['field_value']) . '</p>';`.

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php for more details.